# Дублируются значения при сортировке окон SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Работаю с запросом в базу данных. Необходимо разбить всю таблицу на группы с группировкой по столбцу `finis`. Решил данный вопрос при помощи `partition by`. Далее из получившихся окон выбираю не больше трёх значений отсортированных по столбцу `price`. Далее мне необходимо отсортировать по минимальной `price`сами окна. Максимум чего добился - сортировка производится, но окна при этом дублируются. Думаю это происходит из-за пересекающихся диапазонов значений `price` между окнами. Есть ли возможность решить эту проблему?

```
SELECT * FROM ( 

    *# определяю окна, которые группируются по finis и сортируются по price*

    SELECT *, row_number() over (PARTITION BY finis ORDER BY price ASC) AS num 
    FROM Parts WHERE originality=%s )

    # из каждого окна выбираю по 3 строки c наименьшей ценой и сортирую их по цене

WHERE num <=3 ORDER BY price, num = 1 ASC;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH
cte1 AS ( SELECT *, 
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY finis ORDER BY price ASC) AS num
          FROM Parts 
          WHERE originality=%s ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT *,
                 MIN(price) OVER (PARTITION BY finis) minprice
          FROM cte1
          WHERE num <=3 )
SELECT * 
FROM cte2
ORDER BY minprice, num, price;
```

Первый CTE нумерует записи в группе.

Второй - оставляет по 3 записи на группу и считает минимальную цену в группе.

Основной запрос сортирует. Сначала по минимальной цене (она для всей группы одна и та же), затем по группе (вдруг у двух групп одинаковая минимальная цена - перемешаются ить), ну и потом уже в каждой группе по цене.

В принципе можно и одним CTE обойтись:

```sql
WITH
cte AS ( SELECT *, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY finis ORDER BY price ASC) AS num
         FROM Parts 
         WHERE originality=%s )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE num <=3
ORDER BY MIN(price) OVER (PARTITION BY finis), num, price;
```

но лично у меня душа не лежит к оконным функциям в ORDER BY...

Comment: Если не ORDER BY, то какие в конкретном случае могут быть альтернативы?

Comment: @user441929 не понял вопроса... вот то есть совсем не понял. Не, ну какая может быть альтернатива сортировке, а? только что не сортировать...

Comment: "но лично у меня душа не лежит к оконным функциям в ORDER BY..."
Имел ввиду это )

Comment: @user441929 Ааа... ну так альтернатива показана же - дополнительный CTE.

Comment: Тупанул, извините )